# returning error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have variable deleteboxvalue

```
var deleteboxvalue = "111111111111111";
if(deleteboxvalue.indexOf('0') >= 0) {
    alert("You can't delete all Contact Number.");
return false;
} 
else { 
    alert("All Zeros are not selected."); return true;
}
```

I want to check if 0 is not exist in this I want to return false and alert as "You can't delete all Contact Number." but in both cases if 0 exist in variable in that case also its returning false and giving me alert as "You can't delete all Contact Number."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check if 0 is not exist in this I want to return false

If that's the case then you've got your logic reversed. You are currently returning false if `0` *is* in the string (i.e. it is found at an index greater than or equal to 0). If you want to return false when `0` is not found in the string, you can do this:

```
if(deleteboxvalue.indexOf('0') == -1) {
    alert("You can't delete all Contact Number.");
    return false;
} 
else { 
    alert("All Zeros are not selected."); 
    return true;
}
```

However, I may have completely misunderstood what you're trying to do...

Comment: I meant I have group of boxes for deleting contact number. I have created condition using loop and taken value in variable if checkbox is selected I have added 1 in variable else added 0. FInally I created variable as deleteboxvalue = "111111111111111";
Now I want to check if 0 exist in this I want to return true if 0 doesn't exist I want to return false.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function in JavaScript such as:

   ```
    function CheckContacts() {
       var deleteboxvalue = "111111111111111";
       if (deleteboxvalue.indexOf('0') >= 0) {
           alert("You can't delete all Contact Number.");
           return false;
       } else {
           alert("All Zeros are not selected."); return true;
       }
   }
   ```

   and
2. On body onload call that JavaScript method:

   ```
   <body onload="CheckContacts()">
   ```